# Unable to publish nuget package - github actions

Tags: github-actions, nuget-package

I've built a github action to push my nuget package to github registry based on github docs. When it runs it compiles well but on push it runs to the following error.

```
Pushing XXXXX.1.0.0.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MYACCOUNT'
PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MYACCOUNT/ warn : invalid repo host
'nuget.pkg.github.com', only github (github.com) repositories allowed  BadRequest
https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MYACCOUNT/ 42ms error: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```

Error message is not too verbose.

Api-key is registered in Personal access tokens. It has write/read:packages and full control of private repository permission.

What do I miss here?

Related yaml is the following:

```
name: publish to nuget
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  publish:
    name: build, pack & publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Pack
        run: dotnet pack XXX.csproj -c Release
      - name: Prep packages
        run: dotnet nuget add source --username MYACOUNTNAME --password *** --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MYACCOUNTNAME/index.json"
      - name: Publish to GitHub packages 
        run: dotnet nuget push bin/Release/*.nupkg --api-key ***  --source "github"
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are concerned. After hours of struggle I found the problem.
I had to modify my .csproj file.

```
<RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/MYACCOUNTNAME/EXACT_REPOSITORY_NAME</RepositoryUrl>
```

My issues was that root url was https://nuget.pkg.github.com instead of github.com alone.
What a dumb error message...